# Joomla Article Styling

Tags: css, joomla, article

I want to create an article that will contain a cv. The HTML of the article looks like this:

```
<div class="bio-container">
    <div class="bio">
        <img src="images/cv-girl.jpg" border="0" alt="cv-girl" title="cv-girl" /> 
        <ul>
            <li>Position: </li>
            <li>Physics Lab</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="bio">
        <h4>Paper blabla</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>paper 1</li>
            <li>paper 2</li>
            <li>paper 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="bio">
        <h4>Interests</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>Interests 1</li>
            <li>Interests 2</li>
            <li>Interests 3</li>
            <li>Interests 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="bio">
        <h4>Lessons</h4>
        <ol>
            <li><a href="www.google.com">lesson 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com">lesson 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.google.com">lesson 3</a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <div class="bio">
        <h4>Publishings</h4>
        <div class="public-menu">
            <a href="#" onclick="showHide('books');return false;">Books</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="showHide('magazines');return false;">Magazines</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="showHide('conf');return false;">Conferences</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="showHide('show');return false;">Shows</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="showHide('disc');return false;">Discography</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="showHide('other');return false;">Other</a>
        </div>
        <hr />

        <div id="books" class="anchor-hidden">
            <h5>Books</h5>
            <table border="0">
                <thead> 
                    <tr>
                        <th>A/A</th><th>Title</th><th>Year</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead> 
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>[1]</td>
                        <td>C.K. Georgiadis, P. Fouliras, and A. Manitsaris, "Mobile Agent Platforms and Personalized Multimedia Services Issues", Chapter in "HANDBOOK OF RESEARCH ON MOBILE MULTIMEDIA, 2nd EDITION", I.K. Ibrahim (Ed.), Information Science Reference Inc (IGI Group), September 2008, ISBN 978-1-60566-046-2, pp. 595-611.</td>
                        <td>2008</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>[2]</td>
                        <td>S. Weerawarana, F. Curbera, et al., "Αρχιτεκτονική Πλατφόρμας Υπηρεσιών Ιστού", επιστημονική επιμέλεια ελληνικής έκδοσης: Χρήστος K. Γεωργιάδης, εκδόσεις Κλειδάριθμος, σελ. 455, ISBN 978-960-461-086-0, Αθήνα 2008.</td>
                        <td>2008</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- The rest of the divs for the links goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
.bio img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 1px inset black;
}

.bio:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
}

.public-menu a {
    margin: 5px;
}

.anchor-hidden {
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    display: none;
}
```

The JS function:

```
function showHide(shID) {
    if(shID == "all") {
        document.getElementById("books").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("magazines").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("conf").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("show").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("disc").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("other").style.display = "block";
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById("books").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("magazines").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("conf").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("show").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("disc").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("other").style.display = "none";

        document.getElementById(shID).style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

The template i'm using is [Ja Edenite](http://www.joomlart.com/joomla/templates/ja-edenite)

The problem is, that when I click at the books a tag, the hidden div is displayed but it's not pushing the footer down. (I can't post a screenshot, according to SO policies, so...)

The article is overflowing the footer. I've tried several things so far (trying to fix this for like 7hours now) and I'm either really tired after all this time or there is something I didn't think of.

Any ideas would be mostly appreciated!

Comment: can't you post a link to your website ?

Answer (score 0):

I have just taken you code and added in my own footer div and it worked fine for me.

this is what I used for the footer:

```
<div id="footer" style="text-align:center; height:50px; background-color:#000; color:#FFF;">
    <p>Test Footer</p>
</div>
```

Not sure what styling you have given to the footer but if you have given it positioning for example `position:fixed;`, then I would recommend getting rid of this.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to having floated content on the site. Try adding the following beneath your article:

```
<div class="clr"></div>
```

If you're using an editor which strips empty divs out you could also use a clearfix like bootstrap does:

```
.bio-container:after {
    clear: both;
}
.bio-container:before, .bio-container:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps :)